# Google adsense awlays displays blank

Tags: adsense

I create **an ad unit** with my google adsense account，and add **the sync code piece** into my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        google_ad_client = "ca-pub-2512354990153831";
        google_ad_slot = "4650942105";
        google_ad_width = 728;
        google_ad_height = 90;
    </script>
<!-- index_top_ad_01 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

But it always return empty ""，you can [view the site](http://www.hao0.me)。

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't see any adsense code when I view the source of your website?

Comment: Sorry，I have remove the code，and replace with other ad product.

Comment: Please remove this question in that case. People are trying to help you and find an site without the provided adcode.